# How To Find Highest Value In A Row And Return Column Header and it's value

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, linq

Imagine a row of 5 numeric values in an Entity Framework database, how would I retrieve the top 2 columns of that row including the name of the column and their values? Preferably using LINQ.

For example:

```
a  b  c  d  e
0  4  5  9  2
```

The top 2 values are 9 and 5. I would like to retrieve the values and the column names, c and d.

A more practical example:

```
var row = table.Where(model => model.Title.Contains(a.Title));
```

This line will give me a single row with many numeric values.
I would like something as follows,

```
row.list().OrderByDescendingOrder().top(2);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) this data, but using Linq instead of T-SQL. (or some other SQL dialect)

The basic pattern to do this is to use a [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Queryable_SelectMany__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1____) to transform each row to
an array of key/value pairs that you can do an `OrderByDescending` on.

A somewhat generic pattern for this is below:

```
// The values that we want to query.
// In your case, it's essentially the table that you're querying.
// I used an anonymous class for brevity.
var values = new[] {
    new { key = 99, a = 0, b = 4, c = 5, d = 9, e = 2 },
    new { key = 100, a = 0, b = 5, c = 3, d = 2, e = 10 }
};

// The query. I prefer to use the linq query syntax
// for actual SQL queries, but you should be able to translate
// this to the lambda format fairly easily.
var query = (from v in values
            // Transform each value in the object/row
            // to a name/value pair We include the key so that we
            // can distinguish different rows.
            // Because we need this query to be translated to SQL,
            // we have to use an anonymous class.
            from column in new[] { 
                new { key = v.key, name = "a", value= v.a },
                new { key = v.key, name = "b", value= v.b },
                new { key = v.key, name = "c", value= v.c },
                new { key = v.key, name = "d", value= v.d },
                new { key = v.key, name = "e", value= v.e }
            }

            // Group the same row values together
            group column by column.key into g

            // Inner select to grab the top two values from
            // each row
            let top2 = (
                from value in g
                orderby value.value descending
                select value
            ).Take(2)

            // Grab the results from the inner select
            // as a single-dimensional array
            from topValue in top2
            select topValue);

// Collapse the query to actual values.
var results = query.ToArray();

foreach(var value in results) {
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Name: {1}, Value: {2}", 
        value.key, 
        value.name, 
        value.value);
}
```

However, since you have a single row, the logic becomes much more simple:

```
// The value that was queried
var value = new { key = 99, a = 0, b = 4, c = 5, d = 9, e = 2 };

// Build a list of columns and their corresponding values.
// You could even use reflection to build this list.
// Additionally, you could use C# 7 tuples if you prefer.
var columns = new[] { 
    new { name = "a", value = value.a },
    new { name = "b", value = value.b },
    new { name = "c", value = value.c },
    new { name = "d", value = value.d },
    new { name = "e", value = value.e }
};

// Order the list by value descending, and take the first 2.
var top2 = columns.OrderByDescending(v => v.value).Take(2).ToArray();

foreach(var result in top2) {
    Console.WriteLine("Column: {0}, Value: {1}", result.name, result.value);
}
```

Comment: I think I might of been sitting in the same position for the last 10 hours trying to solve this problem, now that i applied your suggestion I believe you have solved it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Mark it as an answer than!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you do this in linq, but here is a SQL Server query:

```
select t.*, v2.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('a', a), ('b', b), ('c', c), ('d', d), ('e', e)
     ) v(col, val) cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end) as val1,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end) as col1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then val end) as val2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end) as col2
      from (select v.*, row_number() over (order by val desc) as seqnum
            from v
           ) v
     ) v2;
```

EDIT:

Of course, you can do this with massive `case` expressions to get the maximum value:

```
select t.*,
       (case when a >= b and a >= c and a >= d and a >= e then a
             when b >= c and b >= d and b >= e then b
             when c >= d and c >= e then c
             when d >= e then d
             else e
        end) as max_value,
       (case when a >= b and a >= c and a >= d and a >= e then 'a'
             when b >= c and b >= d and b >= e then 'b'
             when c >= d and c >= e then 'c'
             when d >= e then 'd'
             else 'e'
        end) as max_value_col          
from t;
```

The problem is extending this to the *second* value, particularly if there are duplicate values.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. I attempted to apply this query with no luck. Isn't there an easier way to essentially retrieve the column with the highest value in a row?

Comment: @Darius . . . What part of the query is causing the problems?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a collection of items, which can be sorted on one of its properties and you want the two items in the collection with the largest value for this sort property?

```
var result = myItems
    .OrderByDescending(myItem => myItem.MyProperty)
    .Take(2);
```

In words: Order the complete collection in a descending order of MyProperty and take the first two items from the result, which will be the two with the largest value for MyProperty.

This will return two complete myItem objects. Usually it is not a good idea to transfer more properties from objects to local memory than you'll actually plan to use. Use a Select to make sure that only the values you plan to use are transferred:

```
var bestSellingProducts = products
    .OrderByDescending(product=> product.Orders.Count())
    .Select(product => new
    {   // select only the properties you plan to use, for instance
        Id = product.Id,
        Name = product.Name,
        Stock = product.Stock
        Price = product.Price,
    });
    .Take(2);
```